# how to create rich text area dynamically in client browser

Tags: javascript, richtextbox, fckeditor

i  am uses wysiwg... rich text area and i want to create it dynamically at run time

also i uses FCKeditor and try to create new rich text area at run time but here i can' create dynamic rich text area at run time in browser

also when i create new one data in old rich text area mist be persist its value

Comment: keep your mist away from my text area! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use FCKeditor.CreateHTML() or FCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea() for this. You need an (unique) id for each editor.

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically want [Rich Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format), or do you want some kind of formatting that will be in HTML? If you want the latter then  have had success with TinyMCE works well, but there are literally stacks of them, many of which are good.